# Struggling to bind and match DOM elements with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom, selector

I prefer to bind all my DOM elements at the top of my code so that the ID or class reference is only hard coded once, even though the element is used multiple times within the code. Something like this:

```
var startButton = "#startButton";
var closeButtons = ".button.close";
```

That works well with selectors, such as document.querySelector. The challenge occurs when I'm about to compare an element ID to one of the static variables above, like for instance during a click event:

```
e.target.id == startButton
```

Since the variable startButton contains a sharp, I would have to do something like this:

```
e.target.id == startButton.replace('#', '')
```

This is obviously not the ideal way of handling things, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to bind DOM elements for later use?

Please note that I did consider retrieving the elements using a selector right away, like document.querySelector, but that prevents me from manipulating the elements later on.

**EDIT:** My note above turns out to be wrong. It's totally possible to manipulate the elements later on. So the question is whether it's better to store selectors in variables, or to store nodes in variables. As pointed out below, the DOM element might not exist while it's being declared, so it might be better to store the selector in a variable, like I'm doing above.

Comment: Well you're not *really* binding DOM elements; you're just saving the selectors in variables. That's a fine thing to do, but it has precisely the problem you're talking about (and it only gets worse when you start using more complicated selectors).

Comment: I totally agree. How can I solve that problem? Please also read my bottom note.

Comment: It's always better to cache element reference over selector string  in case you are using multiple times

Comment: *"Please note that I did consider retrieving the elements using a selector right away, like document.querySelector, but that prevents me from manipulating the elements later on."*  Please elaborate on why you think this is the case?

Comment: `e.target.id === startButton.slice(1)`

Comment: @Taplar Because that stores the node in a variable. Let's say I want to live change an attribute, like "placeholder" later on - that would change the attribute for the node stored in the variable, but not the actual DOM element.

Comment: No, it changes the dom....

Comment: @Taplar That is not my experience.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/35o8rh62/  This is basic javascript.

Comment: What Taplar says is definitely, 100% accurate.

Comment: Now it **does not** change the view source, but it does indeed change the DOM.

Comment: ___"That is not my experience"___ -   can you reproduce the issue in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You are totally right - that definitely works. I have no idea why I couldn't make this happen previously. Perhaps my code contained bugs. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the specific example in your question, you can use `.matches()`:

```
if (e.target.matches(startButton))
```

The `.matches()` DOM API takes a selector as its argument.

Comment: Nice. The only thing I'd note about this is _having to know in advance whether you're comparing IDs to IDs and not IDs to Classes_ etc.

Comment: @Lewis yes, sure; in the OP's scheme of doing things, keeping track of particular selectors seems to be important. I don't know why, but if the selectors are used variously to *find* things, they can also be used via `.matches()` to *check* on elements.

Comment: This works great! What would be better: To store the ID's and classes in variables? Or to retrieve the elements right away using a selector, like document.querySelector?

Comment: @Chris it depends on the application. I tend to do lots of dynamic DOM updates, so having the selectors kept in variables is a common pattern for me (to avoid dumb typo errors and things like that).  I use jQuery so I'd use `.is()` instead of `.matches()` but they're pretty much the same.

Comment: @Pointy Why would you use selectors in variables instead of nodes in variables?

Comment: @Chris because at the time the variables are declared the nodes may not exist in the DOM.

Comment: @Pointy That totally makes sense. Thanks!